# If point O is the centroid of Triangle ABC, line AD is a median of the triangle, Line OD = x+6, and line AO = x^2 +6x - 20, find AD.

Tags: geometry

If point $O$ is the centroid of Triangle $ABC$, line $AD$ is a median of the triangle, Line $OD = x+6$, and line $AO = x^2 +6x - 20$, find $AD$.

I really need help with this.

Comment: What do you mean by median of the triangle? Also where does x come from?

Comment: It's simple algebra. You're supposed to know that the centroid $O$ is $1/3$ of the way from $D$ to vertex $A$, hence $AO = 2(OD)$.

Comment: You might find this question regarding a similar problem interesting :https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3575449/705917